# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" retrieving multiple records with IOrganizationService

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I am creating a plugin for Dynamics 365 in C#. I am trying to make request using fetchXML, however I am getting the following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Here is my code:

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // Obtain the tracing service
        ITracingService tracingService =
            (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.  
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        IOrganizationService svc = (IOrganizationService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationService));

        try
        {
            var id = context.InputParameters["leadid"] as string;

            var fetchXml = $@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
                <fetch>
                  <entity name=""lead"">
                    <attribute name=""leadid"" />
                    <link-entity name=""new_sitecorevisit"" from=""new_new_parent_leadid"" to=""leadid"">
                      <attribute name=""new_visitduration"" />
                      <filter>
                        <condition attribute=""new_new_parent_leadid"" operator=""eq"" value=""{id}"" />
                      </filter>
                    </link-entity>
                  </entity>
                </fetch>";

            EntityCollection result = svc.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));

            context.OutputParameters["data"] = result;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tracingService.Trace("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I believe that it is being thrown when this line is reached:
`EntityCollection result = svc.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));` as removing this fixes the issue. However, I do not know why it is throwing this error. I have checked to see if it is an error with the fetchXml variable or the id variable, however these are passing as expected.

I have tested retrieving the data using JavaScript and the data is returned as expected, however, this is not useful for creating a .NET plugin.

Is there a mistake that I am making?

Comment: What is the *actual* value of `svc`?

Comment: svc is the  `IOrganizationService` which is equal too `(IOrganizationService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationService))`

Comment: What Hans is asking is to set a breakpoint somewhere before the exception, and ensure that `svc` is a non null value.

Comment: And to elaborate further: that Getservice call *should* return a value, but *does* it really? We cannot say from here

Comment: What happens if, instead, you use `IOrganizationService svc = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOrganizationService>();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @DavidG Using that throws the error `Cannot resolve symbol "GetRequiredService"`

Comment: Do you have a `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` line?

Comment: @DavidG That fixed that error, but now it returns `"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"`